# How to sort a matrix by using values in another vector in matlab?

Tags: matlab, sorting, vector, matrix

My situation is:

I get a 1000*2 matrix and a 1000*1 vector.

And the row i in the matrix is mapped to the element i in the vector.

And the elements in the vector are all integer.

Now I want to sort the elements in the vector from low to high.

And I want to get a new matrix with the sequence of the new vector. And the mapping relationships are equal to the original situation.

How to do this in Matlab?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`sortrows`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sortrows.html):

First concat your vector to your matrix:

```
M2 = [V, M];
```

Then sort rows:

```
M2 = sortrows(M2); %// You should just do sortrows([V, M]) here, I just split it for the explanation
```

Then split the vector and the matrix:

```
V_sorted = M2(:,1);
M_sorted = M2(:, 2:end);
```

Or alternatively you can use the second output from [`sort`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sort.html):

```
[V_sorted, newRowOrder] = sort(V);
M_sorted = M(newRowOrder, :);
```