# Is it possible to sort data depending on time?

Tags: matlab, sorting, date, matrix

I have a matrix (220x19) containing numerical dates on the first row and values corresponding for each date. The problem is that the dates aren't sorted. I want to sort the dates, I know that sortrows() functions exist, however, the dates are sorted, will the data follow the corresponding numerical date?

Comment: There are [2 approaches here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19176189/8239061) that seem relevant if your dates are simply numerical values.

Comment: Please include a [mcve] in your question

Answer (score 1):

Assuming from your description, your Matrix (let's call it A) has the following form:

```
A = [3,    1,    2;
     0.3,  0.1,  0.2
     0.33, 0.11, 0.22]
```

where 3, 1 and 2 in the first row correspond to the numerical dates and the other two rows contain the data. Then

```
B = sortrows(A.')
C = B.'
```

will give you

```
C = [1,    2,    3;
     0.1,  0.2,  0.3
     0.11, 0.22, 0.33]
```

Actually you want to sort column-wise, as I've understood, which is the same as sorting the rows of A transposed.

Comment: Recommend using `.'` for the [`transpose()`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/transpose.html). See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25150319/8239061).